# Cannot duplicate mysql database using phpmyadmin export/import on same server

Tags: mysql, drupal, phpmyadmin

I am trying to duplicate one of my databases on a remote bluehost server in order to setup a dev and stage environment for my drupal website. Dev is already setup/populated and working fine, so I am now simply trying to duplicate the dev database. Using phpmyadmin on windows (PHP 5.2.17, MySQL 5.5.42). I have done the following steps:

1. created site_stage database
2. exported/dumped all tables from site_dev db into compressed sql.gz file
3. imported all tables into site_stage db

Import fails with $1064 error:

```
INSERT INTO `cache_bootstrap` (`cid`, `data`, `expire`, `created`, `serialized`, `tags`, `checksum`) VALUES
('system_list', 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[...]

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 2
```

Thought maybe it didn't like the length of that value, so I just deleted that cache_bootstrap query from uncompressed version of dump file (shouldn't need this cache table anyways) and tried to import again, this time, it failed with the following error:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `key_value` (
  `collection` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'A named collection of key and value pairs.'
`value` longblob NOT NULL COMMENT 'The value.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`collection`,`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='Generic key-value storage table. See the state system for…';

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`value` longblob NOT NULL COMMENT 'The value.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`collection`,`nam' at line 9
```

I've read a lot of '1064 error on import' threads, but none of them help and most of them pertain to moving sql data between servers. Very strange that I would get syntax errors copying tables from one database to another on same server, with same mysql version, etc. Any ideas? Thanks in adv.

Comment: You're missing a comma at the end of the `collection` line.

Comment: I suspect this is a problem with PhpMyAdmin, can you login to the server and use `mysqldump` from the command line?

Comment: yes, that worked. ran `mysqldump -p -u user site_dev > dump.sql`  then `mysql -p -u user site_stage < dump.sql` thanks!

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using?

Comment: phpmyadmin version 4.1.14

Comment: Same issue with v4.4.15.10